# How Do I Prevent An Azure Cloud Service (Classic) From Going To Sleep (In 2018)?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-cloud-services

We have a site that keeps falling to sleep, which causes an error due to the time-sensitivity of our sporadic requests.

I've seen how there is an "Always On" setting in the old Azure console, but it doesn't appear to apply to the new interface:

[How to prevent an Azure website from going to sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789895/how-to-prevent-an-azure-website-from-going-to-sleep?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Where is this setting now, or how do I do the equivalent?

Here's what I see:
[image: Azure Cloud Service Display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of options. One of those is to use [Traffic Manager Endpoint Monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring) which keeps calling your app so it doesn't recycle. Or is automatically started again when it does.

According to the blog post [Windows Azure WebSites and Cloud Services Slow on First Request](http://wp.sjkp.dk/windows-azure-websites-and-cloud-services-slow-on-first-request/) you can "include a script with your package, which is configured to run as a startup script, every time the role is restarted."

```
REM *** Prevent the IIS app pools from shutting down due to being idle.
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00

REM *** Prevent IIS app pool recycles from recycling on the default schedule of 1740 minutes (29 hours).
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00
```

How to proceed with the configuration can be found under "Avoid automatic recycle of Azure Cloud Services Web Role" of that post.

Answer (score 1):

- Check the Cloud Service availability on Azure portal.
- Ensure that all role instances are in a Ready state. If they are not,
  refer to the troubleshooting blade.
- RDP into the role instance and check the IIS process (w3wp.exe) in
  Task Manager is running.
- If the w3wp.exe process does not show in Task Manager, go to [IIS
  Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj635847(v=ws.11)) and restart the application.
- Check the http response code you get in the browser. 50x errors are
  application-related issues, refer to the troubleshooting blade.
- Check that the default ports 80 (for http) and 443 (for https) are
  accessible. Use TELNET or TCPING to ensure that the w3wp.exe process
  is listening on it.
- If your web application is accessible locally but not externally, it
  could be a network-related issue.

You may want to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404801/cloud-service-always-on-not-working) as well.